# CSS3 nth-child doesnt work Chrome 9

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-selectors

hey all, i have this code:

```
    <div class="sidebox">

            <h3>Course Summary</h3>

            <div class="block">

                <h4>Course ID</h4> 
                <p>MS00000001</p>
                <h4>Start Date</h4> 
                <p>14<sup>th</sup> September 2011</p>
                <h4>End Date</h4> 
                <p>12<sup>th</sup> June 2012</p>
                <h4>Cost</h4> 
                <p>£1500.95</p>     

            </div>

        </div>
```

now im trying to change the colour of every second P tag

```
.sidebox .block p:nth-child(odd) {
    color: red !important;
}
```

i tried using that but it didnt work :/ nothing changes colour, am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Matt Ball says, [elements are 1-indexed](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) instead of 0-indexed. Therefore your `p` elements are even children, not odd, so they won't be matched at all. Another catch is that `:nth-child()` takes into account every sibling under that parent, no matter the type, so if you use `p:nth-child(even)`, *every* `p` gets selected.

Use `p:nth-of-type(even)` instead so non-`p` siblings (in this case, `h4` elements) are excluded from the selection:

```
.sidebox .block p:nth-of-type(even) {
    color: red !important;
}
```

[Sample on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/SpsUC)

Answer (score 4):

There is no `p` element which is an odd child in your markup. CSS `nth-child` is 1-indexed.

> The index of the first child of an element is 1.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)

Comment: so how would i select every second P ?

Comment: No, that would select every `p` because they're all even children.

Comment: @BoltClock: you're right, I didn't understand what the OP was asking. Thanks :)